# Lock GTK3 Paned interface from allowing resizing

Tags: gtk3

Is there any way to lock GTK3 Paned, so that user can't even attempt to resize the panes/children?

Reason for the question is interacting on a not very big touch screen with 3 panes containing 4 scrollable lists in [quodlibet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and as a wide area of [±50px](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/863b399899e0a835cde7de111e20900a036738f4/gtk/gtkpaned.c#L720C9-L720C31) around the handles for touch events starts the resizing, there is not really much space left to interact with the widgets inside. Is there any simpler way than replacing the Paned widget with Box widget and moving all children to lock resizing and back with Paned to unlock?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand exactly what you want, but it seems to me that you want to prevent the user from moving the **Gtk.Paned** separator. If that's the case, one way is to set a minimum size for child widgets of **Gtk.Paned** using **Gtk.Widget.set_size_request()**.

Thus, the user can still move the separator when there is enough space, but will not be able to move it when the space reaches the defined minimum limit.

Comment: Unfortunately will not help, as my goal is to lock/hide resizing interface, as with a touch device it gets in the way of interacting with child widgets. I've tried to rephrase title and question

Comment: Welcome to post Gtk+2 frustration. I'm sure there is a way to do it. Maybe just have the `.move_handle` function return `NULL`? [Gtk.Paned Gtk+3](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.Paned.html) (this doesn't get rid of the horrible waste of 50px through ...) There also has to be some "un" or "under" documented css node for the handle size you can set to 0 or so. Got to love it. Documentation is always the last to get done.