# GTK3 container children dimensions customisation

Tags: python, gtk3

I would like to put 2 widgets into a container (horizontally or vertically) so that they fill it, but be able to set which part of width/height they take, like 33% or 40% for the first one, rest for the second.

I tried using a Gtk.Box, packed both children inside (tried combinations of fill/expand for both), connected `size-allocate` to a function in which I use `set_size_request` on first child using `allocation.width`/`allocation.height` and desired ratio, but children get some random sizes until container gets resized (for example when resizing window).

Is there some better container option, some better way to manage children sizes or am I just missing setting some flag/calling some method at some point?

[Lock GTK3 Paned interface from allowing resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76815286/96823) caused this.

Comment: do you get correct sizes after resizing container? maybe it needs to run some `updata()` or `repaint()` to inform `GUI` that it has to redraw it.